# Nuxt.js v2 serves uncompressed .js files in production as if it was in development

Tags: nuxt.js

When I run "nuxt build" and then "nuxt start" on localhost, the app behaves just as it should:

1. .js files are in _nuxt/bbb7f01.js (or something similar)
2. files are compressed (gzip)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpTGU.png

However, when I run the app on server using "nuxt build" and then starting it with PM2 as suggested here: https://v2.nuxt.com/deployments/pm2/ the app runs as if in DEV mode:

Files are huge and not compressed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBzQR.png

Thanks!